# Get access to array and sort it from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

Imagine i have an array that contains some values:

```
let countryName = ["USA", "Canada", "Italy", "Israel"]
```

When button is tapped its starts sort this array by regions:

```
let countryToRegionDic = [
    "United States" : "America",
    "Czech Republic" : "Europe",
]

func useFilter() {
    self.countryName.forEach({ (country) in

        let countryRegion = self.countryToRegionDic[country]

        if (countryRegion != nil && europeFilter.contains(countryRegion!)){

            self.filtered.append(country)
            self.countryName = self.filtered.removeDuplicates()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }           
    })
}
```

What i want its use this sorting function in another "FiltersViewController" , because values for filtration i get from this "FiltersViewController". Think I need to use delegates or protocols but don't know how and where. Thank you!

Comment: If you're going to use that function in other controller maybe you could develop it in an UIViewController extension

Comment: Note sure i got what u mean. I get data to "countryNames" array in ViewController A and sort it by depending data in ViewController B

Comment: Then `delegate´ pattern is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks i'ill search info about it

Answer (score 0):

A little example about delegation patter...

```
public protocol CountrySort: class
{
    func sorted(_ array: [String]) -> Void
}

public class ControllerA
{
    public var countryName: [String]!

    public weak var delegate: CountrySort?

    public func userFilter() -> Void
    {
        // Do something here...
        countryName.sort()

        self.delegate?.sorted(countryName)
    }
}

public class ControllerB
{
    public init()
    {
        // Call the other UIViewController
        let controllerA: ControllerA = ControllerA()
        controllerA.countryName = ["USA", "Canada", "Italy", "Israel"]

    }
}

extension ControllerB: CountrySort
{
    public func sorted(_ array: [String]) -> Void
    {
        print("And now the other controller sort the array")

        for item in array
        {
            print("\t\(item)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'ill  try  to implement this today!